# How to multiple binding to IValueConverter?

Tags: c#, uwp

On UWP(Windows 10 platform), `IMultiValueConverter` is not supported.

How to multiple binding for this textblock

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtContentMessage"
           Text="{Binding Text}"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           Foreground="{Binding Entities,
               ConverterParameter={Binding Text},
               Converter={StaticResource ChangedColorToUrlConverter},
               Mode=TwoWay}"
           MaxLines="3"
           Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [MDSN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Sharepoint/en-US/467424ee-dd54-45ec-bdc0-512a2b5d4923/uwp-is-imultivalueconverter-available-for-uwp?forum=wpdevelop) you can use [DependencyProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyproperty.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396&cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1).

Or, one of the method described by Magnus, bind a list of `values` and use a converter.

```
public IList<object> Values
{
   get { return new List<object> { this.Entities, this.Text }; }
}
```

XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txtContentMessage"
           Text="{Binding Text}"
           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" 
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           Foreground="{Binding Values,
               Converter={StaticResource ChangedColorToUrlConverter},
               Mode=TwoWay}"
           MaxLines="3"
           Grid.Row="1"/>
```

And write `Convert` for the `List` object.